# How can I access Firestore database via http-get restful API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've created an cloud firebase type database in firebase. Plz have a look at the image below. But How to access the datas from API(get)? If I use real time database, simply 'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json' this url gives the json data. But using cloud firebase database, I'm unable to get json data. I've tried to use "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/EmployeeApp/name=employeeapp-66646/newsFeed/" but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an example of a URL for one of my databases:

https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project-8080059325282098184/databases/(default)/documents/52679469/docid

An explanation of the variable parts in here:

- `project-8080059325282098184` is my project ID.
- `(default)` is the name of the database. At the moment you can't specify a name for your database, so yours will be `(default)` too.
- `52679469` is the name of my collection.
- `docid` is the name of my document

The JSON I get back:

```
{
  "name": "projects/project-8080059325282098184/databases/(default)/documents/52679469/docid",
  "fields": {
    "field1": {
      "stringValue": "value1"
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2018-10-06T14:16:24.090837Z",
  "updateTime": "2018-10-06T14:16:24.090837Z"
}
```

In this response:

- `name` is the full path of this document.
- `fields` is the data of the document.
- `createTime` and `updateTime` are the metadata for the document.

Comment: Use Google API Explore. So much easier https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1/

Answer (score 8):

The following URL will do the trick:

https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/employeeapp-66646/databases/(default)/documents/newsFeed

Have a look at the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls), for detail on how to build the URL.